# Install android on windows 8 tablet

Tags: boot, usb, tablet

I have a Windows 8 tablet (an [Asus VivoTab](https://www.asus.com/Tablets/ASUS_VivoTab/)) and I want to dual boot it with android but I am having a rough time figuring out how to flash the android iso to tablet. It has no cd, usb or microSD port. I also thought about booting from network but I don't see this feature in BIOS settings. I read a couple of tutorials about it but all of them tell to burn a usb stick (like [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-android-windows-8-tablet/) one). The only port my tablet has, is that small micro-B usb where I can't really plug any memory sticks. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What is the make and model of your tablet?

Comment: @Burgi ASUS VivoTab

Comment: Is the booting from the network related to installing/using Android? (If not, then please [remove](http://superuser.com/posts/1074484/edit) that from your question. We want one question per post.)

Comment: Would something like [this](https://www.asus.com/Tablet-Accessory/ASUS_VivoTab_Series_External_Extension_Kit/) work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I decided to spend a few bucks on dual USB flash drive so that I can plug it to micro USB port. Actually I was wondering whether there is a way to flash iso to tablet memory with something similar to ADB but this also works fine.